# Entity framework 4 : blocking behavior with Oracle

Tags: entity-framework

I am using WCF 4 deployed in IIS 8 on a win 2008 server (4 core) and Devart for oracle 11g.
Multiples application (70 clients) are calling on each 10 seconds an operation (getStatusData) that should return a small array of result (1 kb). This is a scheduled call to keep the clients updated by polling...

In the service application logs on server side I could see that sometimes the server take a little more than 30 seconds to answer (as is it blocked in the middle of the response...)

One of the changes that I have made :

- initialy I was using a per request pattern for entity framework : I was using the same context for a call.
- now due to some memory leak I am using a context per thread.

During this wcf call I am querying, updating on a specific table : I suspect that all my calls in order to query or update on this table are blocked...  But I am not sure of that...
Have you got any idea on what is going on here ?

**Added for a complete understanding**

Here what my application is doing :

```
//Here what my service method look like :
ResultStatus GetSetInfo(Guid clientId)
{
   var info = Repo.GetInfo(clientId);
   info.LastPoll = DateTime.Now;
   Repo.SetInfo(clientId,info);
   return info;
}

//Here my repository Repo :
public class Repo
{
   ObjectContext GetContext()
   {
      //Return ObjectContext by threadId (stored in a concurrentDictionnary)
      return ArrContexteByThread[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId];
   }
   InformationStatus GetResult(Guid clientId)
   {
      var contexte = GetContext();
      IQueryable<InformationStatus> query = (contexte.InformationStatus.Where(cli=> (cli.ClientId == clientId)));
      var objectQuery = (ObjectQuery) query;
      objectQuery.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
      var infoStatus = query.FirstOrDefault();
      return infoStatus ; 
   }

   public ResultStatus GetInfo(Guid clientId)
   {
      var info   = GetResult(clientId);
      if(info == null) 
            return new ResultStatus (clientId);

      return GetResultFromInfosStatus(info);

   }

   public void SetInfo(Guid clientId, ResultStatus  status)
   {
      var contexte = GetContext();
      var info   = GetResult(clientId);
      if(info == null) {
         info = new ResultStatus (clientId);
         contexte.AddToResultStatus(info);
         contexte.SaveChanges();
         return;
      }

      ResultStatus status = GetResultFromInfosStatus(info);
      var key = status.EntityKey;
      object infoKey;
      if (contexte.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out infoKey))
          contexte.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, status);
      contexte.SaveChanges();

   }

}
```

Comment: Per-Request is the correct pattern for EF, so you've probably chosen the wrong path there.  But in any case you now need to ensure that you do not have a long-running transaction.

Comment: I am not sure that this is the root cause of my problem : I have read that Entity Framework DbContext is not threadSafe so it seems ok to create a dbContext per thread... Why could I not use a long running transaction ? I am not observing any object locked at the DB level ... Is it possible that Entity framework is causing the lock itself?